# HTTP request in swift 3 Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am getting stuck with HTTP request.it did not show any error.compiler reads the first two lines and skip the code to "task.resume()".i am fetching data with same code on other view controller but it creats problem here

```
func getCustomers()
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "myURL.com")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) {
        (data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error))")

            return
        }
        do
        {
            self.getcustomersArray = [GetCustomers]()
            //JSON Parsing
            if let data = data,

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
            {
                let results = json["Result"] as? [[String : Any]]

                let getCustomersObject:GetCustomers = GetCustomers()
                for result in results!
                {
                    getCustomersObject.ActivityPrefix = (result["ActivityPrefix"] as? String)!
                    getCustomersObject.CustomerID = (result["CustomerID"] as? String)!
                    getCustomersObject.CustomerName = (result["CustomerName"] as? String)!
                    getCustomersObject.TFMCustomerID = (result["TFMCustomerID"] as? String)!
                    getCustomersObject.ShortName = (result["ShortName"] as? String)!
                    getCustomersObject.UserRights = (result["UserRights"] as? Int)!

                    self.totalCustomers += self.totalCustomers
                }
                self.customerName = getCustomersObject.CustomerName

            }
        }//end Do
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Its obvious because completion block of `dataTask` will call later when you get response

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what is the problem it is creating ?

Comment: @ch umer solved your problem?

Comment: @NiravD thanks for your answer actually i am new in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Block GET/POST/PUT/DELETE:**

```
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "Your API URL here" ,param: param))!,
        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
        timeoutInterval:"Your request timeout time in Seconds")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers as? [String : String] 

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {data,response,error in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if (error != nil) {
         print(error)
         } else {
         print(httpResponse)
         }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           //Update your UI here
        }

    }
    dataTask.resume()
```

I think you dont mention line
request.httpMethod = "GET"

Comment: For a GET request an explicit `URLRequest` is not needed and in Swift 3 use native `URLRequest` rather than `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Comment: Thank you for share your knowledge. I mean that he missed request httpMethod.

Comment: Basically the code in the question **is** working, GET is the default.